# Removing entity with cascade

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa

**Code:**

```
@Entity
class Teacher implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    String name;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "teacher",cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    List<Course> courses;
}

@Entity
public class Course implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    String name;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    Teacher teacher;
}
```

Three questions:

1. **Must I put** `CascadeType.REMOVE` **in both entities?** I want it to work so that if I delete the teacher the course will be deleted automatically.
2. In my database my id doesn't work normally. I want it so that the id increments by one each time, but it currently increases by some random number. **Why?**
3. I have 2 more `@Entity` Classes but with `@ManyToMany` relationship. **What must I to do when I want to persist a new object in the database?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Probably a duplicate of one of these:
   [JPA: Cascade remove does not delete child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15909336/jpa-cascade-remove-does-not-delete-child)
   [JPA 2.0 orphanRemoval=true VS on delete Cascade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329577/jpa-2-0-orphanremoval-true-vs-on-delete-cascade)
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22237631/jpa-does-not-cascade-delete-operation-from-parent-entity-to-child-entity
   Have you checked those references?
2. Need more intel
3. You can persist each of them alone or an instance of Class A with an instance of Classe B attached or vice versa (assuming that you are using the proper `CascadeType` and `@ManyToMany` relationship and persistence framework that understands those two)

Comment: many thanks, the delete on cascade work perfectly.the 3 question my question is what i must to do if i want to persist entity if i have @ManyToMany relationship.

Comment: I'm glad it works. Edited my answer about question number 3. If you need, i can find a real example to help clarifying it